# iOS QLPreviewController Left to Right page swipe

Tags: ios, qlpreviewcontroller, pdf-reader

The default implementation of PDF viewing using  QLPreviewController is swipe pages top through bottom. Is there anyway I can make it work from left to right swipe?

```
QLPreviewController *previewVC = [QLPreviewController new];
previewVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
previewVC.dataSource = self;
[self.parentViewController presentViewController:previewVC animated:YES completion:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
}];
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes.

Add the Following Sourcecode

```
UI.touch.run
```

Then

```
[[UIApp.Swipe.ltr = handleall.pdf]]
```

In a Nutshell the First code Declares the New Touch Scheme

The 2nd One is for Inner Code

Add that to your code and restart your iOS Device

Note: May not work on all Versions of iOS